# Python Unittest Mock assert_has_calls returning calls to other mocks

Tags: python, mocking

Here's a toy example that illustrates my problem.

## Code

```
class Bar:
    def do_a_thing(self):
        print('doing a thing')


class BarSupplier:
    def get_bar(self) -> Bar:
        return Bar()


class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar_supplier: BarSupplier):
        self.bar_supplier = bar_supplier

    def do_foo(self):
        self.bar_supplier.get_bar().do_a_thing()
```

## Tests

```
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, call

from calls_example import Foo


class TestCallsExample(TestCase):
    def test_once(self):
        bar_supplier = MagicMock()
        bar_supplier.get_bar.return_value = MagicMock()

        foo = Foo(bar_supplier)

        foo.do_foo()

        bar_supplier.get_bar.assert_has_calls([
            call(),
        ])

    def test_twice(self):
        bar_supplier = MagicMock()
        bar_supplier.get_bar.return_value = MagicMock()

        foo = Foo(bar_supplier)

        foo.do_foo()
        foo.do_foo()

        bar_supplier.get_bar.assert_has_calls([
            call(),
            call()
        ])
```

## Results

The first test passes.

The second test fails, with the following exception:

```
Failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
AssertionError: Calls not found.
Expected: [call(), call()]
Actual: [call(), call().do_a_thing(), call(), call().do_a_thing()]
```

This feels like really strange behaviour - I'm asserting about calls to the `get_bar`  method on the `bar_supplier` mock, but then the calls list includes calls to a different mock which is returned by the `get_bar` method.

I'm sure this is a misunderstanding rather than a bug, but how can I best avoid getting those `.do_a_thing()` calls in my list of calls?

Comment: See related https://bugs.python.org/issue43371

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the same mock for `.get_bar()` always subsequently calls `.do_a_thing()` which as [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_has_calls):

> ##### `assert_has_calls(calls, any_order=False)`
>
> assert the mock has been called with the specified calls. The **`mock_calls`** list is checked for the calls.

Wherein [mock_calls](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.mock_calls) includes not just the calls to itself:

> ##### `mock_calls`
>
> mock_calls records all **calls to the mock object**, its **methods**, magic methods and **return value mocks**.

#### Solution 1

You can use the `any_order=True` setting for [assert_has_calls](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_has_calls) which as documented:

> If `any_order` is false then the calls must be **sequential**. There can be extra calls before or after the specified calls.
>
> If `any_order` is true then the calls can be in **any order**, but they must all appear in mock_calls.

So change:

```
bar_supplier.get_bar.assert_has_calls([
    call(),
    call()
])
```

To:

```
bar_supplier.get_bar.assert_has_calls([
    call(),
    call()
],
any_order=True)
```

#### Solution 2

An alternative is checking [call_args_list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_args_list) instead:

```
assert bar_supplier.get_bar.call_args_list == [
    call(),
    call()
]
```

Comment: I don't want to do any order, though, because in the real production case (rather than this toy example) I want the calls to be in a specific order. Also, it's not the same mock. I'm asking for calls to the `get_bar` method of my `bar_supplier` mock, which is set to return a different MagicMock.

Comment: The `call_args_list` tip is helpful, thanks. It's a pity there's no direct assertion for that.

Comment: @PaulDavies I forgot the `assert` command, make sure to add it :)